# How to query ONE record from GraphQL (instead of a list)... my example is always passing the same id

Tags: asp.net-core, graphql, vuejs3, quasar

I am using GraphQL in Quasar Vue 3.

On a button click, I need to get one User based on userId.

But the code I have here, is always passing the same userId (it is always passing 42, which is the initial value).

Here's my state:

```
const state = reactive({
  selectedUserId: 42,
});
```

Here's my query:

```
const getOneUserQuery = gql`
  query oneUser($id: Int!) {
    oneUser(userId: $id) {
      id
      firstName
      lastName
    }
  }
`;
```

Here, I call the query, I'm passing the selectedUserId:

```
const oneUserResults = useQuery(getOneUserQuery, {
  id: state.selectedUserId,  //this will end up passing 42 every time
});
```

Here's my button event where I need to get this User:

```
async function onClickSubmit(userId: number) {
  state.selectedUserId = userId; //here I'm setting selectedUserId to a new value
  console.log(state.selectedUserId); //this confirms that I set it to a new value other than 42
  const fetchedUser = await oneUserResults.refetch();
  console.log(fetchedUser);
  if (fetchedUser) {
    console.log(fetchedUser.data);
    console.log(fetchedUser.data.oneUser);
    console.log(fetchedUser.data.oneuser.id); //this user returned from the database will always be the one with userId = 42
    console.log(fetchedUser.data.oneuser.firstName);
  }
}
```

The problem is that no matter what user I click on, it always sends userId 42.
42 is what I initialized selectedUserId with.
And I verified that state.selectedUserId is getting set.

But it looks like when it makes this call, it uses the initial value of selectedUserId, NOT the value that it gets set to:

```
const oneUserResults = useQuery(getOneUserQuery, {
  id: state.selectedUserId,
});
```

With this in mind, is there another way to do this code?
I would actually like to have the "loading" property in there like this, but I cannot get this to work at all:

```
const { result: oneUserResult, refetch: oneUserFetch, loading: oneUserLoading,} = 
useQuery(gql`
  query oneUser($id: number!) {
    oneUser(id: $id) {
      id
      fileContent
    }
  }
`);
```

NOTE: I don't know what syntax I would use to call the above code in a button event handler, and also pass it a UserID.
I only know that if I were calling it on page load, I would call it like this:

```
const state = reactive({
  oneUser: computed(() => oneUserResult.value?.oneUser),
});
```

If I wanted to call it in a button event handler without passing it an Id I could do this:

```
oneUserFetch();
```

But this doesn't pass the id, and it doesn't return a result.

I'm new to GraphQL and I don't know the syntax for things yet.

Thanks

UPDATE:
One of the commenters gave me the answer.
And now here's the result.
This is working for me now:

```
const state = reactive({
  loading: oneUserLoading,
});

const { refetch: oneUserFetch, loading: oneUserLoading } = useQuery(gql`
  query oneUser($id: Int!) {
    oneUser(userId: $id) {
      id
      firstName
      lastName
    }
  }
`);


async function onClickSubmit(userId: number) {
  state.loading = true;
  if (!userId) return;
  const fetchedUser = await oneUserFetch({ id: userId });
  console.log(fetchedUser);
  if (fetchedUser) {
    console.log(fetchedUser.data);
    console.log(fetchedUser.data.oneUser);
    console.log(fetchedUser.data.oneUser.id);
    console.log(fetchedUser.data.oneUser.firstName);
  }
  state.loading = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GQL queries normally use cache data but we need to update it by using refetch().
But if refetch doesn't use new params, query will return cache data again.
So refetch function should use new params like below.

`refetch({ id: selectedUserId })`

This answer was posted to you on Upwork too.

Thanks
Bohdan

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful.  I didn't realize how GraphQL cached the data unless you give it new parameters.